# Qual a melhor forma de gerar Push notification usando o Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho um sistema que onde é possível registrar uma serie de tarefas a serem cumpridas por uma equipe ou pessoa. O que eu preciso é que sempre que um pedido for finalizado por um usuário, todos os outros recebam uma notificação (Push) dizendo que foi concluída.

Minhas duvidas são:

a) Supondo que usuários podem entrar ou sair dos grupos solucionadores, o que seria mais recomendado. Mandar o Push para: Topics, Groups ou single devices?

b) Como impedir que o Push seja gerado após o usuário fazer log-off no app?

Os grupos solucionadores teriam um modelo parecido com grupos do What’s app. Se o usuário sai do grupo, ele deixa de ser notificado.

Answer (score 0):

a) Resposta curta: **Topics**.

Resposta longa:

**Single devices** exigiria que você crie sua própria lógica para o utilizador entrar e sair dos grupos. Você teria de guardar o token de cada utilizador num banco de dados (o que pode sair mais caro, dependendo dos limites do seu banco de dados).

**Groups** - apesar de o nome ser sugestivo, [a documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group?hl=pt-br) indica que os grupos servem para você mandar um push para todos dispositivos que pertencem a um utilizador. Por exemplo, se um dos seus utilizadores usa a app no iPhone, em um tablet Android e em um computador (pela Web), você colocaria esses 3 dispositivos num grupo para receberem sempre as mesmas notificações.

**Topics** - tal como nos groups, você não precisa gerir os tokens de cada dispositivo que faz parte de um "grupo" (diferente do single devices) pois o Firebase é que faz isso por você. E o SDK é muito fácil de utilizar. Para um utilizador juntar-se à um grupo, você faria:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("idGroup");
```

E para ele sair do grupo:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("idGroup");
```

b) Se você estiver utilizando o Firebase Auth, ao fazer o log off ele irá deixar de ter acesso às push notifications. Caso não esteja utilizando o Auth, experimente chamar [`deleteInstanceId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#deleteInstanceId()) durante o log off.